# Issues getting logged out in angular oidc library

Tags: javascript, angular, openid-connect

I currently going through a problem that keeps me getting logout at random times, It is very hard to reproduce the error but when I am using the application at some point I got logged out and and redirected to the login page and when I click on sign-in button the app logged me in without credentials. To me it seems like some state problem within oidc lib or some configuration problem in my app or some delays from server.
I am using the following lib https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client for my angular application.

My config:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        authority: environment.authConfig.authority,
        redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/sign-in',
        clientId: environment.authConfig.clientId,
        scope: environment.authConfig.scope,
        responseType: environment.authConfig.responseType,
        unauthorizedRoute: '/sign-in',
        silentRenew: true,
        useRefreshToken: true,
        startCheckSession: environment.platform === 'pwa',
        renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 20,
        configId: environment.configID,
        ignoreNonceAfterRefresh: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: AbstractSecurityStorage, useClass: AuthStorage }],
  exports: [AuthModule],
})
```

and I am using the following code to get the access token on my route guard on every page change.

```
return await this.zone.run(async () => {
  try {
    let result: LoginResponse;
   
      result = await firstValueFrom(this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuthIncludingServer());
      

    if (result?.isAuthenticated) {
      await this.handleLoginResponse(result);
      return true;
    }
    if (result?.errorMessage) {
      this.notificationService.showError(result.errorMessage);
      this.authenticated = false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    this.notificationService.showError('Login Error: ' + error);
    this.authenticated = false;
    return false;
  }
});
```

I tried to console log the **result** and I got null at some point and was being logged out but there were no errors and I couldn't manage to pinpoint where actually the problem originated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 const result = await firstValueFrom(this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth());
```